# Filter data from database using v-for

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4

Here I tried making a const data inside the script(vue js).

```js
data() {
    return {
    event: [],
    items: [
      [id: '1', month:'January', date:'01'],
      [id: '2', month:'February', date:'03'],
    ]}
}
filter(val) {
  let items = this.items;
  let filter = items.filter(el => el.month === val);
  this.event = filter;
}
```

And had this in my `v-for`

```vue
<h1 v-for="(item, id) in event" v-bind:key="id"></h1>
<p>{{ items.month }}</p>
```

It loops the filtered items from the empty event array.

Since my const data is too many. I tried creating an API.

And this is how I get the data from database.

```js
data() {
  return {
    Items: [],
  }
}

getHoliday(){
    getTest.getHoliday()
            .then(response =>{
                this.Items = response.data;
            })
    },
```

And loop through it using `v-for`

```vue
<h1 v-for="(Item, id) in Items" v-bind:key="id"></h1>
<p>{{ Item.month }}</p>
```

From here, I only know how to call the specific data through mustache. I can't do the filter that I use when using const data.

Comment: It depends if you are calling the `getHoliday()` method.  You can try calling `getHoliday()` in your mounted maybe. Or you could try computed properties as it was mentioned before

Comment: Data from the database should really be filtered by the DBMS. Any client side filtering scales poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can filter data from backend via [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

```javascript
computed: {
    filteredItems() {
        return this.Items.filter((item) => {...});
    },
},
```

in your template you can iterate over this new property

```html
<h1 v-for="(Item, id) in filteredItems" v-bind:key="id">{{ Item.month }}</h1>
```